# Converting NTP timestamp to datetime in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, ntp

In Python, I have a 64bit floating point number representing a NTP time. I like to convert that in a readable format, e.g. a datetime object.

According to wikipedia the first 32 bit contain the time since 1970, and the last 32 bit are fractions of seconds, which I'm not interested in. However, as I have a float, not an int, how can I access the first 32 bit only? Bitshift doesn't work...

Comment: How are reading the data from what sensor?

Comment: @Klaus D. via serial (the sensor is USB).

Comment: You should not expect any helpful answer without providing your code, the sensors specification and the exact data send and received (best in ASCII and HEX).

Comment: @Klaus D. Sorry, I rephrased the question, it was probably misleading. Communication is no problem, and I know that I have an NTP time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ntplib](https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/) python module has functions to convert from datetime timestamp to NTP timestamp and back.

```python
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()
print("timestamp:", dt)

# convert datetime to NTP time
ntptime = ntplib.system_to_ntp_time(dt)
print("NTP time: ", ntptime)

# convert NTP time to datetime timestamp
ts = ntplib.ntp_to_system_time(ntptime)
print("timestamp:", ts)

# convert system timestamp to datetime
print("datetime:", datetime.fromtimestamp(ts))

# convert 1-Jan-1970 epoch datetime to NTP time
ntptime = ntplib.system_to_ntp_time(0)
print("\nNTP time: ", ntptime)
ts = ntplib.ntp_to_system_time(ntptime)
print("datetime:", datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone.utc))
```

**Output:**

```
timestamp: 1631063844.829307
NTP time:  3840052644.829307
timestamp: 1631063844.829307
datetime:  2021-09-08 01:17:24.829307+00:00

NTP time:  2208988800
datetime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: The portion to the right of the '.' place seems incorrect.  In the NTP format, it is in units of 1/2^32.  Whereas in datetime format, it is in units of 1/1,000,000.  So, the numbers should not be same, but they are both 829307.

Comment: Value right of decimal is fractional seconds. If want NTP 1/2^32 fraction then can call ntplib._to_frac(ntptime) which is used internally when setting the NTPPacket data.